# How should i attach jsons to variable/another json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

It should be answer here but I can't find.
I have script like this:

```
 for (count=1;count<5;count++) {
      obj[count]=json[count]
  }
```

Then I want connect this. But I made it manually:

```
objs=[...obj[1].posts,...obj[2].posts,...obj[3].posts,...obj[4].posts]
```

How I can automatically connect all this. Like this:

```
 for (count=1;count<5;count++) {
      obj[count]=json[count]
objs+=[...obj[count].posts]
  }
```

Example:

```
var obj=[];
var objs=[];
obj[1]=[123]
obj[2]=[456];
obj[3]=[789];
```

Should get:

```
objs=[...obj[1],...obj[2]...obj[3]]
alert(objs)
```

Will result: 123,456,789

Comment: If you're asking whether it works, have you tested it yourself?

Comment: What do you mean by "json" in the title  do you mean a JavaScript object or a JSON formatted string?

Comment: I mean `objs=[]`. I don't know what it is. I am not good in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry because I am dumb. I used `objs,push(obj)` with loop. Now I don't need loop of creating value. It now work well.
Script that I use now if you need:

```
obj=[]
for (count=1;count<5;count++) {
//Your script that gets json
...
//If your json is string (i don't know is every json in internet is string)
      json=JSON.parse(json string that you get
obj.push(...json.posts) //You can change "posts" with array/object (I dont know what is this) that you want or without it if json is  clean array
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By using : `filter` & `map`

```
var obj=[];
var objs=[];
obj[1]=[123]
obj[2]=[456];
obj[3]=[789];

objs = obj.filter(Boolean).map(a=>a[0])
```

Comment: I can't use second one (es9 only). Tried use first one but it not work. Maybe I wrote something wrong. But `alert(result.posts)` not work. Tried with other address like .file .src

Comment: Updated the answer. i thought you are merging objects not arrays.

Comment: I don't know what I make wrong. Added example how it should be. Can you write full script in comment?

Comment: updated the answer again. hopefully is what you want this time.

Comment: It work, but I need connect`obj[x].posts`. When I use your answer with that this give me [,,,]. And writing `obj.posts` don't give me anything

Comment: is that what are you trying to do?
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h1xdkm4e/2/)

Comment: It work for example. It's not answer of my question. In script I tried to use (code before example) make`123456789`, not `123,456,789`. Your answer work well when there only one array ([123]), not for `obj[x].obj` (x is any number of obj )